# Why does switching the order of for loops significantly change the execution time?

Tags: c++, vector

In the following code, I have 2 nested for loops. The second one swaps the order of the for loops, and runs significantly faster.

Is this purely a cache locality issue (the first code loops over a vector many times, whereas the second code loops over the vector once), or is there something else that I'm not understanding?

```
int main() 
{ 
  using namespace std::chrono;
  auto n = 1 << 12;
  vector<int> v(n);

  high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int i = 0; i < (1 << 16); ++i)
  {
    for(const auto val : v) i & val;
  }
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
  std::cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds.";
  std::cout << std::endl;

  t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(const auto val : v)
  {
     for(int i = 0; i < (1 << 16); ++i) i & val;
  }
  t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
  std::cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds.";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified in the disassembly of this program that the compiler hasn't simply optimized away some of the loops?

Comment: @cdhowie. No, I'm not sure how to do that as I've never looked at assembly code before. Do you have a reference?

Comment: [See here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/NxauiK) -- both gcc and clang optimized away both loops at `-O3`. It's measuring quite literally nothing.

Comment: Compilers are quite good these days. When benchmarking, you must use the results for something, and make it hard enough that the compiler won't short-circuit your computations and simply precompute the result.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica Ah I see. Is there any way to know before compiling if a compiler will precompute the result?

Comment: @lamanon No there is not

Answer (score 1):

As written, the second loop needs to read each val from vector v only once. The first version needs to read each val from vector v once in the inner loop for every i, so in total 65536 times.

So without any optimisation, this will make the second loop several times faster. With optimisation turned on high enough, the compiler will figure out that all these calculations achieve nothing, and are unnecessary, and throw them all away. Your execution times will then go down to zero.

If you change the code to do something with the results (like adding up all values i & val, then printing the total), a really good compiler may figure out that both pieces of code produce the same result and use the faster method for both cases.

Comment: Does reading values from vector more increasing the execution time because of cache locality? I was under the impression that because it's a single vector with contiguous elements, cache locality isn't an issue.